# python3 and smbpasswd package

Tags: python-3.x, passwords, samba

I have a python utility with which I have been successfully  managing our /etc/smbpasswd and /etc/samba/smbpasswd files for over 12 years. Time to update it to Python 3 !

I found that the latest [smbpasswd](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/smbpasswd) installs in Python3, but doesn't load.

What is the best way to solve this using smbpasswd compatibility? I am not looking at replacing the working system with tdbsam!

Answer (score 3):

Even with the update of the package in 2011 python 3 had been out for a few years, so I assumed it is dead code.

There is an easy solution, install [passlib](http://pythonhosted.org/passlib/) with pip and create a file `smbpasswd.py` file with the following content:

```
import passlib.hash

def lmhash(s):
    return passlib.hash.lmhash.encrypt(s).upper()

def nthash(s):
    return passlib.hash.nthash.encrypt(s).upper()
```